# HttpWebRequest with proxy - setting cookies

Tags: c#, cookies

Here is my code:

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/jsonrpc.cgi");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "someParameters";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string Bugzilla_logincookie= httpResponse.Headers.ToString();
        Bugzilla_logincookie= Bugzilla_logincookie.Substring(plsWork .IndexOf("logincookie") + 12);
        Bugzilla_logincookie= Bugzilla_logincookie.Substring(0, plsWork .IndexOf(";"));

        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
        cc.SetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost"), Bugzilla_logincookie);
        var httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/jsonrpc.cgi");
        httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest2.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        httpWebRequest2.CookieContainer = cc;

        using (var streamWriter2 = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "someParametersForJsonCall";
            streamWriter2.Write(json);
        }
        var httpResponse2 = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader2 = new StreamReader(httpResponse2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader2.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I have problem with using proxy. The thing I'm trying to do is: use a Proxy for http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/User.html to call the login method and then store cookies of response and send them with each call of the session.
I get this error:

```
"You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla."
```

What am I mistakenly using?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (exept i do not face it in bugzilla but in my own app)